# Stanford NLP: Keeping punctuation tokens?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am looking for sentences such as

> Bachelors Degree in early childhood teaching, psychology

- I annotate the text using the Stanford Parser.
- I then iterate each sentence and identify "Bachelor's Degree" using NER (named entity recognition).
- By processing triples, I can see that the object follows "BE IN" and is likely to be a college major.
- So I send the object phrase for further analysis. My trouble is that I don't know how to separate

> early childhood teaching

from

> psychology

My code for this procedure loops through the object triple and keeps it if certain POS requirements are met.

```
private void processTripleObject(List<CoreLabel> objectPhrase )
{
    try
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(CoreLabel token: objectPhrase)
        {
            String pos = token.get(CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);

            TALog.getLogger().debug("pos: "+pos+"  word "+token.word());
            if(!matchDegreeNameByPos(pos))
            {
                return;
            }

            sb.append(token.word());
            sb.append(SPACE);
        }

        IdentifiedToken itoken = new IdentifiedToken(IdentifiedToken.SKILL, sb.toString());

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        TALog.getLogger().error(e.getMessage(),e);
    }
```

Since the comma between teaching and psychology is not in the tokens, I don't know how to recognize the divide.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `token.get(CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class)` will return the token if no POS tag was found. Tested with CoreNLP 3.7.0 and `"tokenize ssplit pos"` annotators. You can then check if `pos` is in a String with punctuation points you are interested in. E.g this some code I just tested:

```
String punctuations = ".,;!?";
for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
    for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
        // pos could be "NN" but could also be ","
        String pos = token.get(CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
        if (punctuations.contains(pos)) {
            // do something with it
        }
    }
}
```